# How to show that $\sqrt[n]{3}$ is not a real root of a polynomial of degree $<n$, where $n\geq 2$.

Tags: polynomials, roots

How to show that $\sqrt[n]{3}$ is not a real root of a polynomial of degree $<n$, where $n\geq 2$.

Suppose for some $f(x)=a_{k_1}x^{k_1}+\cdots+a_{k_s}x^{k_s}$ with $n>k_1>\cdots>k_s$, $a_{k_i}\neq 0$, $\sqrt[n]{3}$ is a root of $f$, then by dividing both sides by $(\sqrt[n]{3})^{k_s}$, we may assume $b_1(\sqrt[n]{3})^{l_1}+\cdots+b_s=0$, with $l_1>l_2>\cdots>0$. Then how to derive a contradiction?

Comment: Probably you may want to add that you consider polynomials with rational coefficients, because otherwise $x-\sqrt[n]{3}$ would do the job.

Comment: After making the assumption that you are looking for polynomials with rational coefficients, if you analyse the sum you get after dividing by $3^{k_s/n}$, you are saying that the sum of a rational and an irrational quantity is 0. What does that mean?

Answer (score 3):

By  [Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) applied to $f:=X^n-3$ with $p=3$ we see that this polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ and has $\xi:=\sqrt[n]{3}$ as one of its roots. Thus $f$ is the *minimal polynomial* of $\xi$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I was in the midst of giving an answer substantially equivalent to this (but longer, since I can not avoid prolixity). The one other thing I would have had was an explicit argument that since $f$ is irreducible, any $g$ with $g(\xi)=0$ must be divisible by $f$. Anyway, plus one for this.

Comment: @Lubin: Typing on a Tablet keyboard is cumbersome. So I try to be as Shirt as possible. 